# Sample size calculation for positive predictive value of test in cross-sectional study

Tags: sample-size

I am looking for the right approach to do a sample size calculation for the positive predictive value in a cross-sectional study. From external sources, I know the prevalence in the population of interest. I also have an estimate of the sensitivity and specificity of the test. My question is now: How many subjects do I have to include in the study in order to show that my positive predictive value is above some value, with a confidence level of 95% and a power of 80%?

The literature I found so far is on the more complex case of a case-controlled study, such as https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3668447/. That paper seems to refer to Pepe, The Statistical Evaluation of Medical Tests for Classification and Prediction (2003) for my case, but I do not have access to it. I'd be grateful if anyone could share the applicable formulas for this sample size calculation!